# Extracting a portion of a value out of a database column using SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to extract a portion of a value out of a database column using SQL server.
The example below works in a simple context with a varchar field. The result is: &kickstart& which is what I want.

I now want to do the same when retrieving a column from the database.
But SQL does not like what I am doing. I'm thinking it is something easy that I am not seeing.

```
Declare @FileName varchar(20) = '&kickstart&.cfg'
Declare @StartPos integer = 0
Declare @FileNameNoExt varchar(20)

SELECT @FileNameNoExt = Left(@FileName,( (charindex('.', @FileName,  0)) - 1))
SELECT @FileNameNoExt
```

Here is the SQL statement that I can't seem to get to work for me:

```
Declare @FileNameNoExt as varchar(20)

SELECT 
    i.InstallFileType                                  AS InstallFileType,
    o.OSlabel                                          AS OSLabel,
    SELECT @FileNameNoExt = (LEFT(oi.FIleName,( (charindex('.', oi.FIleName,  0) ) - 1) )) AS FileNameNoExt,
    oi.FIleName                                        AS FIleName
FROM
    dbo.OperatingSystemInstallFiles oi 
    JOIN dbo.InstallFileTypes i ON oi.InstallFileTypeId = i.InstallFileTypeId
    JOIN dbo.OperatingSystems o ON oi.OperatingSystemId = o.OperatingSystemId
```

Comment: which SQL database are you using? It looks like MS SQL-Sever

Comment: You are probably getting a syntax error.  Change `SELECT @FileNameNoExt = (LEFT(, etc` to `aliasName = left(etc`.  Then figure out how to get your aliasName into a variable.

Comment: Added `sql-server` tags based on the code given

Comment: Thanks @DanBracuk. I actually did not need a variable at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the variable at all?  What's wrong with:

```
SELECT 
    i.InstallFileType                                  AS InstallFileType,
    o.OSlabel                                          AS OSLabel,
    LEFT(oi.FIleName,( (charindex('.', oi.FIleName,  0) ) - 1) ) AS FileNameNoExt,
    oi.FIleName                                        AS FIleName
FROM
    dbo.OperatingSystemInstallFiles oi 
    JOIN dbo.InstallFileTypes i ON oi.InstallFileTypeId = i.InstallFileTypeId
    JOIN dbo.OperatingSystems o ON oi.OperatingSystemId = o.OperatingSystemId
```

Comment: I see that now. I actually don't not need a variable at all....thanks to @DanBracuk suggestion. And to you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You've put a `SELECT` inside another `SELECT` list without nesting, which is a syntax error in SQL Server.

You are also attempting to assign a variable while performing a data-retrieval operation. You can select all data to be shown, or all data into variables but not both at the same time.

When the two issues above are resolved, I think you may still run into issues when committing filenames into a variable which only allows 20 characters - but then I don't know anything about your dataset.